# Where to set the coverage runner in Android Studio Chipmunk?

Tags: android-studio, code-coverage, jacoco, android-jacoco

In Android Studio 4.1.2, it can set the coverage runner for JaCoCo at

[image]

but in Android Studio Chipmunk (2021.2.1), there is no place to choose JaCoCo as the coverage runner

[image]

How to run the JaCoCo coverage test in Chipmunk?

**Update:**

As @Daya Nithi point out, there is a `Modify` options for choosing the runner.

But after that the test does not run, with "*Test events were not received*". Any suggestion for it?

[image]

Comment: Seems it is a bug in chipmunk. tests are running fine in bumblebee

Answer (score 2):

Click on Modify options and click specify alternate coverage runner. Now you can choose jacaco

Comment: Thanks @Daya Nithi! It can set the jacoco tunner now. But the the test does not run anymore (with "Test events were not received")

Answer (score 0):

i met the same problem, events not received